# ¿Como queda el modelo relacional?

Tags: sql

[image: Ejemplo.]

Se genera la tabla Proveedores_Productos, y esta lleva inmerso como atributos el código del proveedor y el código del producto mas la fecha de envió, la pregunta es, la tabla productos ya no necesita el código del proveedor por redundancia de datos o me equivoco, espero de sus aportes

Comment: Hola @Jose. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]!¿Podrías aclarar si estás hablando de 1 sola tabla, 2 tablas diferentes o 1 tabla para la relación entre otras 2 tablas, o una vista? No  me queda claro desde el gráfico qué de todo eso es una tablay qué es una relación. ¿Cuáles serían los campos de cada tabla? ¿Podrías listarlos? De esa forma sería más sencillo entender si hay redundancia de datos y poder contestarte.

Answer (score 1):

efectivamente no es necesario 
- El código proveedor no es un campo propio de la entidad producto y la relación que existe entre proveedor y producto (n x x) se refleja en la tabla proveedor-producto.
- La tala proveedor-producto contiene la información necesaria y suficiente para determinar que producto, que cantidad y quien fue el proveedor. 
- Si colocas el código proveedor dentro de producto tendrías que crear un producto para cada proveedor y si tienes 5 proveedores que te proveen del mismo producto? tendrías que crear 5 registros del mismo producto pero con distinto proveedor.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda brindada amigo.
Saludos.

Comment: Estamos para ayudar, saludos.